# How to detect rivers or obstacles in google maps development

Tags: google-maps

I want to implement a following scenario in google map:
   An image of vehicle automaticly drives on google map. To be safe, it should never go across a building or a river.
Is there any APIs or opensource projects to avoid the obstacles or the rivers in google map? Or how to detect the obstacles and the rivers on the map?

Comment: When you say a vehicle automatically drives on google map, do you mean an image of a vehicle driving on a Google Map or do you mean an actual vehicle using the data from Google Maps?

Comment: An image of a vehicle drives on a google map. The key is to detect the obstacles and the rivers on the map, but how?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the Google Maps Directions API, which will provide routing that uses bridges and doesn't drive through buildings?

Comment: I want to plan path in my own way rather than the shortest path in Google map. Therefore, Google Maps Directions API doesn't help.